# Terminal says invalid sytax (new to Python)

Tags: python, syntax

I've looked around and I can't seem to find an answer to this on this website.

I'm taking a class to learn Python and we have our first project, which led me to type up this code:

```
>>> year_str = input("Predict the population growth of the United States in a number of years in the future: ")
>>>
>>>year_int = int(year_str)
>>> 
>>> year_len = 31536000
>>> 
>>> birth = (((year_len * year_int)//7) + (((year_len * year_int)%7)//7))
>>>
>>> death = (((year_len * year_int)//13) + (((year_len * year_int)%13)//13))
>>>
>>> immigr = (((year_len * year_int)//40) + (((year_len * year_int)%40)//40))
>>> 
>>> growth = birth - death + immigr
>>> 
>>> pop1 = 318354218
>>> 
>>> pop2 = pop1 + growth
>>> 
>>> print("The new population in",year_int,"year(s) will be", pop2)
>>>
```

I've taken out the lines wtih results on them such as the input prompt and the print output.

However, when I try to open the .py file, I get this message for a split second:

```
File "C:\Users\X\Documents\Python\proj01.py", line 1
 Python 3.4.1 <v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 1 2014, XX:XX:XX> [Msc v.1600 32 bit <Intel>] on win32
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `>>>` from every line.

Comment: I thought I had done that already, but it turns out that I'd missed one. Thanks a ton